# Editing SharedParameterFile/Deleting Shared Parameter Entry

Tags: c#, revit-api

I want to create a parameter for a document, and associate to it a Guid so that I can uniquely reference it later on. In order to do so, I want to look for other parameters in the document with the same name/Guid and delete them. If I simply do so, Revit will complain that there is already another Parameter with the same Guid in the document, and this is due to the fact that such a Guid is present in the SharedParameterFile.

So my question is: is there a way through the Revit API to delete the entry of a parameter from the SharedParameterFile?

Comment: This is not an answer, I think you won't find an editor through the API, but you might be able to get the location of the shared parameter file, and then you build your reader/editor of the `txt` file.

Answer (score 1):

In the Revit API, there isn't a direct way to delete an entry from the Shared Parameter File programmatically. However, you can achieve a similar effect by creating a new Shared Parameter File that excludes the unwanted entry.

1. Create a new File representing the Shared Parameter File.
2. Copy the necessary entries from the existing Shared Parameter File to the new File, excluding the entry you want to remove.
3. Replace the existing Shared Parameter File with the newly created one.